# Anaconda 4.3, 64-bit (python 3.6), leaves incorrect truncated paths in windows Start menu

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

After installing anaconda 4.3 64-bit (python 3.6) on windows, and choosing "install for current user only" and "add to path":
I noticed that the anaconda program shortcuts don't work on my start menu--they are cut off at the end.  Does anyone know how the correct entries should read?  (or instead, how to repair the links?) thanks.

*UPDATE: I reproduced the problem on two other machines, Windows 10 (x64) and windows 8.1 (x64), that were "clean" (neither one had a prior installation of python).*

This is what they are after a fresh install (under "Target" in "Properties" in the "Shortcut" tab for each shortcut item):

JUPYTER NOTEBOOK:
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3 "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/python.exe" "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Loc

JUPYTER QTCONSOLE:
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3 "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe" "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/L

SPYDER:
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3 "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe" "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/L

RESET SPYDER:
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3 "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/python.exe" "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Loc

NAVIGATOR:
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3 "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe" "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/L

IPYTHON:
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3 "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/python.exe" "C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Loc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed in the newest build of anaconda (4.3.0 **.1**).  Unfortunately looks like it requires uninstall and reinstall as the locations seems to have changed drastically (from some subsubsub folder off of AppData to something higher up, under user directory). 
(But that might be the effect of testing 4.3.0.1 on a different machine.)
For example, ipython is now:
C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3 "C:/Users/user_name/Anaconda3/python.exe" "C:/Users/user_name/Anaconda3/Scripts/ipython-script.py"

Here is changelog for 4.3.0.1:
*In this “micro” patch release, we fixed a problem with the Windows installers which was causing problems with Qt applications when the install prefix exceeds 30 characters. No new Anaconda meta-packages correspond to this release (only new Windows installers).*

Comment: This is correct.  Sorry for any trouble this has caused you.